# Limitation of MAC addresses

Tags: networking, ip-address, tcp, mac-address

A mac address is of only 48 bits. That means there can be only 2 power 48 mac addresses. If for every computer/laptops if the mac address is unique, then there can be only 2 power 48 computers/laptops which is contradicting!! help me out

Comment: 2^48 mac addresses is enough for every single person on the planet (assuming 7 billion) to have about 40,000 network cards. How many network cards do *you* have? :-)

Comment: Actually, MAC addresses must only be unique on the LAN where the host with that MAC address is. MAC addresses (layer-2) are only relevant, or even seen, on the layer-2 LAN. IP (layer-3) addresses cross networks, and thy must be unique across the networks they traverse. Ports (layer-4 addresses) must be unique in side a host, per layer-4 protocol.

Comment: Can there be two computers with same mac across the whole world?

Comment: Theoretically yes since in some systems you can actually change the MAC address to whatever you want. Since MAC addresses used for switching then it'll only cause an issue if two hosts on the same network segment will have the same MAC address and even then it'll just cause the switch not to store this specific MAC in its table and it'll flood the frame destined for these MACs through all of its ports within that segment. Hope it helped...

Comment: One of the 48 bits designates that the MAC address is locally administered, which means it isn't required to be globally unique.  Therefore, each person on the planet is only allowed to have about 20,000 network cards.  LOL.  My company build systems that utilize a LAN with only devices that we control, so we can use locally administered MAC addresses, and assign or reuse the values.  On the other hand, some companies that have been assigned an OUI block have chosen to reuse addresses that you might intuitively think would be globally unique, but aren't,