# Will MAC ADDRESS ever run out of combinations?

Tags: mac-address

**Mac addresses** is made of only 12 digits containing 0-F. So, will they eventually run out of combinations, since each computer has a unique physical address?

Comment: I found some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038010/limitation-of-mac-addresses

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/268006/199731

Comment: Obligatory XKCD reference. https://xkcd.com/865/ (not MAC, but same difference)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unlikely, at least any time soon. There are 16^12=2.81E14 possible MAC addresses, which works out to about **40 thousand** MAC addresses per person on Earth.

Comment: NOTE: A precious version of my answer suggested that the number per person was in the billions (not thousands). Thanks to @José Manuel Martinez for catching my error. As the number is still gigantic, you still don't need to worry about running out!

Comment: This disregards the fact that the first 6 digits are vendor specific, so in reality the number of viable addresses is much much lower than that

Comment: So the size of the MAC space is only a problem in some very futuristic world where we have billions (quadrillions?) of IoT devices everywhere, e.g., in our appliances, bodies, building materials, food, air, plants, wildlife.  Maybe not in our lifetime. 

Answer (score 9):

There is some concern that MAC addresses may be exhausted in about 80 years.  The IEEE [EUI-64](https://standards.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-standards/standards/web/documents/tutorials/eui.pdf) standard prevents such an event, which extends the size of MAC addresses from 48 bits to 64.  Alternatively, hardware vendors may be able to simply recycle old MAC addresses from long-gone devices (e.g., junk over ~20 years old).